# Scala implicit conversion of primitive to AnyRef

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion

In Scala code that I am writing, I have a `Map[String, AnyRef]`. When I try to initialize the Map using the following, Scala complains that it is expecting a `Map[String, AnyRef]` but the value is a `Map[String, Any]`:

```
val myMap: Map[String, AnyRef] =
  Map("foo" -> true, "bar" -> false)
```

I know that I can use the following instead:

```
val myMap: Map[String, AnyRef] =
  Map("foo" -> true.asInstanceOf[AnyRef], "bar" -> false.asInstanceOf[AnyRef])
```

I declared the following in scope:

```
implicit def booleanToAnyRef(value: Boolean): AnyRef = value.asInstanceOf[AnyRef]
```

but the compiler still complains.

Shouldn't the compiler use the implicit method to convert the primitive boolean values into `AnyRef` values? Is there any way, short of (the ugly) `x.asInstanceOf[AnyRef]` to have these converted?

Comment: Any reason you can't use a `Map[String,Any]`?

Comment: I'm passing it to old Java code that expects a Map[String, AnyRef] (after conversion).

Comment: Since only Scala cares about whether it's an `Any` or `AnyRef` (it's all `Object` to Java), you could always cast the map itself from `Map[String,Any]` to `Map[String,AnyRef]`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the record, as the other answers suggest, the latest compiler will say:

> Note: an implicit exists from scala.Boolean => java.lang.Boolean, but
>   methods inherited from Object are rendered ambiguous.  This is to
>   avoid a blanket implicit which would convert any scala.Boolean to any
>   AnyRef. You may wish to use a type ascription: `x: java.lang.Boolean`.

The latest compiler will always be a friend who gives better advice than the friend you used to hang with and get into trouble together with.

Comment: `Map("s"->true).asInstanceOf[Map[String, AnyRef]] + ("t"->(true: java.lang.Boolean))`

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid such implicit conversions between general types (and compiler suggests it). If you want to use `java.lang.Boolean` instead of `scala.Boolean` you can do it this way:

```
import java.lang.Boolean._
val myMap: Map[String, AnyRef] = Map("foo" -> TRUE, "bar" -> FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just say that you're using java's booleans:

```
scala> def foo(x: AnyRef) = x.toString
foo: (x: AnyRef)java.lang.String

scala> foo(true: java.lang.Boolean)
res0: java.lang.String = true
```

or define the following implicit:

```
scala> implicit def b2B(x: Boolean) = java.lang.Boolean.valueOf(x)
//foo: (x: Boolean)java.lang.Boolean

scala> foo(true)
//res1: java.lang.Boolean = true
```

for the numeric types (but not for the Boolean) there is .underlying method:

```
scala> 1.underlying
//res2: AnyRef = 1
```